# <a href=...> syntax

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink

I am trying to append a link to the text as shown below:

```
<a href=\"http://blog.sysil.com/?page_id=5\">Contact Us</a> <br />Copyright © 2010 Stanley Lee. All Rights Reserved.
```

However, it is not linking properly. Do you know what is causing the linking error? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: How could i put two queryString in href of <a>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backslashes (`\`) before the quotation marks in your anchor tag are the problem; you only need those if you are trying to escape them in a string of a programming language (for example PHP).

Try:

```
<a href="http://blog.sysil.com/?page_id=5">Contact Us</a>...
```

Comment: I tried removing the backslashes, but Wordpress is still automatically adding them for me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wordpress. The question didn't originally mention that little detail. :)

Comment: Just a thought: you might try using single quotes `'` instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Read http://tutorialblog.org/use-embedit-to-add-html-code-in-wordpress/ on how to add HTML to wordpress.

Quote: "Sometimes you may just be able to copy and paste code or write HTML code directly into your posts. To do this, you just need to click the HTML tab at the top of the post and then write or paste the code into your post and publish it."

Going to the HTML tab and inserting the code there should prevent WordPress from adding extra backslashes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the backslashes that precede the double quotes and the link should work fine.